# How can I find the javafx.scene.Node that corresponds with a specific org.w3c.dom.Node?

Tags: javafx

If I've loaded an html page on a JFXPanel then I can explore the surrounding org.w3c.dom.Node tree and find nodes that matches specific search criteria. At the end of this process all I get is a single org.w3c.dom.Node

If I want to find the nodes that are positioned up, left, down or right to the org.w3c.dom.Node in the Scene, the first thing I need to do is to find the corresponding javafx.scene.Node that was created from parsing the original html page.

I've been unable to find examples about how to do this. Any help is welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It sounds like you are assuming the `WebView` implementation is to parse an HTML file, and create JavaFX UI nodes corresponding to the HTML elements and then lay them out. I don't think that's the way it works: I think the `WebView` uses a native web view and displays native graphics.

Comment: You are right, I made some assumptions that does not seems to be right. By reading more documentation and exploring javafx source code I come to the conclusion that what I wanted to do cannot be done.My second best approach right now is to use javascript to extract the boundaries of every html fragment in the web page and use that information in Java using the w3c DOM object model